# Как определяется спряжение для глаголов с приставкой ВЫ?

Tags: орфография, спряжение

Как известно, **приставка ВЫ создает определенные трудности** для выбора личных окончаний глаголов.

Например:

***вышить ― вышьешь,*** спряжение определяется по форме ***шьёшь*** (без приставки ВЫ, с ударным окончанием);

***Выдержать ― выдержишь,*** спряжение определяется  для глагола держать (искл., 2-е спр.).

Но есть и не такие стандартные варианты. Как, например, проверить безударный глагольный суффикс и определить спряжение для глаголов ***выставить, выпрямить, выронить, выстрелить?***

Меня интересует **школьная методика** определения спряжения (как надо отвечать на олимпиаде или просто на уроке).

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В этом случае используется обычный способ определения спряжения: глагол  без приставки вы- оканчивается на безударное -ить, не исключение - значит, это глагол 2 спряжения. Вряд ли кто-то в этих глаголах в инфинитиве перед -ТЬ напишет Е вместо И, но, если и возникнут сомнения, что маловероятно, тогда нужно посмотреть на личные окончания глагола, и хотя бы одно из них, в котором ребёнок не сомневается, подскажет спряжение и безударную гласную перед -ТЬ.

Comment: Хотелось бы проверить безударный суффикс И в этих глаголах. Это можно сделать без словаря, применив какое-либо правило?

Comment: Только личные окончания, я думаю. Спряжение определяешь по ним, а потом выбираешь Е или И в инфинитиве перед -ТЬ. Других способов я не знаю, подожду ответов. Интересно.

Comment: Меня всегда смущала пара глаголов: ронять - выронить, но ровнять - выровнять. Почему они пишутся по-разному?

Comment: А статья http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=41#pp41 вам, Sharon, не может помочь насчёт окончаний глаголов?

Comment: @ Леопольд-мэтр  Спасибо, я отвечу вам в поле ответа.

Comment: Для носителей правило не так уж и сложно. А вот для иностранцев правило сложное. Ведь они не знают, когда окончание ударное, а когда нет.

Comment: @Серж
   Ну не скажите. иначе зачем Лопатин правила написал, не для иностранцев же.  К тому же этот суффикс постоянно приходится контролировать в причастиях и деепричастиях. Да и в личных окончаниях и окончаниях прошедшего времени тоже, например:  клеить, клеил, клею, клеят, клеит, склеенный, склеив. Буковки И, Е, Ю, Я, только выбирай.

Comment: Дело в том, что спряжение глаголов по окончанию действует только для оно безударное. Но как иностранцу определить, когда оно ударное, а когда нет?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ по комментарию

1. Спасибо,  я прочитала материал   **[по ссылке](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=41#pp41)** (раньше  меньше внимания уделяла правилам Лопатина). Отчасти это помогло  при анализе пар ***ронять/выронИть*** и ***ровнять/выровнЯть***.

В этих случаях **по спряжению** видно, сохраняется ли глагольный суффикс (неусекаемая основа) или не сохраняется (усекаемая основа):  ***выронИть — вырон/ишь, выровн/Я/ть — выровн/Я/ешь.***

Мы видим, что при спряжении  глагола «выровнять»  суффикс ***Я*** сохраняется.

**Примечание**

Существует такая **закономерность:**

(1) Глаголы **с неусекаемой основой** всегда относятся к 1-ому спряжению, соответственно, поэтому не требуется определять их спряжение по обычному правилу:  ***мешать – мешает*** – неусекаемая основа, суффикс А сохраняется; это глагол 1–ого спряжения.

(2) Глаголы **с усекаемой основой** могут относиться как к 1-ому, так и ко 2–ому спряжению:  ***плескать – плещут***, колоть – колет, махать – машет, пахнуть – пахнет – 1-ое спр., усекаемая основа;  ***смотреть – смотрит*** – 2-ое спр., усекаемая основа.

2. Здесь еще накладывается тема  **[«Способы образования видовых пар глаголов»](https://grammatika-rus.ru/sposoby-obrazovaniya-vidovyh-par-glagolov/) .**

И вот у этих глагольных пар он разный: префиксально-суффиксальный  (***ронЯть – выронИть***) и префиксальный (***ровнЯть – выровнЯть***)