# Конченый бык / конченная работа

Tags: орфография

Правильно я мыслю? Я про кол-во *н*.

`Этот конченый бык однажды нам ворота вышибет.`

`Этот конченный на всю голову бык однажды нам ворота вышибет.`

`Этот сверхконченный бык однажды нам ворота вышибет.`

`Моя конченная работа скоро будет-таки доставлена вам, сэр.`

Comment: "Я про кол-ло *н*". Наверное, *кол-во*? И ещё: *вышиб**е**т*.

Comment: Спасибо. Однако почему всё-таки *выбить* – I спр.? Там же-с *-ить*, и это не исключение.

Comment: Леопольд, дружище, если уж менять на ***е***, то везде. (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) Думаю, что приставка **вы-** тут имеет значение. У *Sharon*, если я правильно помню, когда-то был про это вопрос. "Щаз" найду...

Comment: Вот, нашла: *Как определяется спряжение для глаголов с приставкой ВЫ?* (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447405/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%92%D0%AB) Хороший вопрос, правда? Нужный. Поддержу-отмечу (чегой-то я пропустила... и все, похоже, пропустили...).

Comment: Надо писать *щас*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%81%2C+%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B7&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=50.

Comment: Ну-у... Словечко в необычном употреблении и написании я взяла в кавычки (как рекомендуют правила). Из Нацкорпуса (так тоже пишут, это же разговорный вариант): *— **Щаз** торговаться пойду, — шепнула уголком рта сестра, пригладила всклокоченную шапку...* (Наринэ Абгарян. Всё о Манюне); *— **Щаз!** — угрожающе прошипел Шурик...* (Татьяна Соломатина. Акушер-ХА! Байки).

Comment: Строго не рекомендую эту чушь использовать! Ngram Viewer уже всё показал, а *щаз* даже Викисловарь не признаёт. В русском мы оглушаем конечные согласные, так что говорить, что кто-то по-русски говорит *щаз*, – это не по-Леопольдовому, так сказать.

Comment: Я всё же до сих пор не понимаю, почему *вышибить* – II спр.

Comment: *Строго не рекомендую эту чушь использовать!* **?!** А если не совсем строго, в качестве окказионализма?